# Android BroadcastReceiver null

Tags: android, localbroadcastmanager

I get this exception

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
>          at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
>          at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
>          at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5390)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

but I can't see where is it thrown in my code, and I can't find out how prevent it.
I can't reproduce this issue, but it occured at my users.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: looks like you have registered a receiver object which is null

Comment: IntelliJAmiya I can't, beacuse I have a pretty large code and I don't know where is the problem. I use several broadcast receivers.
Sjd thanks, I'll check it.

Comment: you can debug,it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastReceiver you registered went out of scope or you attempted to register null object. Stop app on line where you register receiver in debuger and see if it is a null.

Comment: Thanks. I register a lot of receivers, so I can't find out where does it happens, but I will check all of them.